# How do i populate selection box based on database entries that match session variable

Tags: php, session, select, while-loop

Im attempting to populate selection boxes with a list of items that have an attribute that match a set session variable, however no results are loading

//My external php file which is getting the cups and the teams associated with them, as well as setting a session variable for the cups

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //checking if submit button was clicked

  include_once 'dbcon.php';

  $cname = $_POST['cupname'];

  if (empty($cname)) {
      header("Location: tables.php?field=empty"); //return them if fields are empty
      exit();
  } else {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE cup_name='$cname'";
      $show_teams = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $numberCheck = mysqli_num_rows($show_teams);

      if ($numberCheck < 8) {
      header("Location: ../teams.php?team=5"); //Take to cup page if there arent enough teams in the cup
    }else {
      $_SESSION['c_cname'] = $cname;
      header("Location: ../tables.php?tables=1");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

//my attempt at loading the results

```
    <select name="team-1" required>
    <option value='Holder' disabled selected>Team 1</option> <!--Placeholder for Select-->
      <?php
      $cupname = $_SESSION['c_cname'];

      if(isset($_SESSION['c_cname'])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE cup_name='$cupname'";
        $show_teams = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          echo "<option>$show_teams</option>";
      }
      ?>
    </select>
```

i need a list of teams associated with that cup loading into my selection box, im pretty sure i need to use a while statement, but unsure how to include it. Example are appreciated

Comment: What you need is a tutorial on the basics, IMHO. This site is not meant to teach you those. Please go _read up_ on how to output the result of a MySQL query in a loop in PHP somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop right after you get the results:

```
     $show_teams = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show_teams)) {
        echo "<option>$row['column_name, like team']</option>";
     }
```

Make sure to replace `'column_name, like team'` with the actual column name you want to display.

UPDATE: based on comments, store the options in a variable which can be echoed in the HTML:

```
<?php
    $cupname = $_SESSION['c_cname'];
    $team_options = ''; // setup variable to hold options

    if(isset($_SESSION['c_cname'])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE cup_name='$cupname'";
        $show_teams = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show_teams)) {
            // put the options in a variable
            $team_options .= "<option>$row['column_name, like team']</option>";
        }
    }
```

Now, later in the HTML:

```
<select name="team-1" required>
    <option value='Holder' disabled selected>Team 1</option> <!--Placeholder for Select-->
    <?php echo $team_options; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: i need to echo the option within my html though, otherwise it will appear in the wrong place

Comment: This does echo the option in the right place. A better option would be to place the output in a variable, then echo the variable in the right location.

Comment: could you possibly provide an example of this?

Answer (score 1):

You are only executing the query, you need to loop over it to get results from database using [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

We cannot just use the result set as it is a resource, not an array.

Replace:

```
$show_teams = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "<option>$show_teams</option>";
```

With:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_teams)) {
 echo '<option value="' . $row['ID-COLUMN'] . '">'. $row['NAME-COLUMN'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: is there a syntax issue here, sorry im new, the solution is throwing Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\xampp\htdocs\friendlyfixtures\tables.php on line 92

Comment: @breadley, thanks for pointing it out. Please check the updated answer now.

Comment: unfortunately still getting no results despite it not showing any errors, is it possible the issue is due to the php being external?

Comment: @breadley, only solution to this is: debug. Print: `sql`, `$_SESSION['c_name']`, you will get the clue. Its not too complex.

Comment: i can say that it is loading one blank result if that helps?

Comment: Print SQL and execute in PhpMyAdmin or any of your favourite MySQL editor.

Comment: The results print when i place the external php file in my html, but only show one blank result when its placed externally in action/table-action.php